# How big is console.assert() overhead?

Tags: javascript, assert

I use `console.assert` at a lot of places in my Javascript library. It's a good practice from software development point of view (it's easiest form of unit testing). But I would like to know how much it will affect the performance of my library when run in production.

- Can browsers skip `console.assert`s when they get some kind of indication that the code is not running in development environment? e.g. Devtools is not open in Chrome
- Can the bundling utilitiles like JS minifiers or Webpack/Browserify allow options to filter out `console.assert`s?

Comment: The answer for your performance question is the same as for all performance questions – measure it.

Comment: Can they? Of course they could. Whether they actually do, you can easily try out. Run an assertion with the console closed and see whether it logs anything. Read the documentation of the minifier and look for these options.

Comment: No, while a browser could return early from `console.assert` without doing anything when the console is closed, it cannot prevent the arguments to the function call from being evaluated. `var i=0; console.assert(++i);` will always end in `i == 1`.

Comment: Here's simple jsperf test I setup to test the performance overhead https://jsperf.com/console-assert-oh/1 The overhead is noticeable!